# Make ng-click behave like ng-changed

Tags: angularjs

How can I make the ng-click behave like a ng-changed? Because every time I click the button it will send a data through AJAX. So the x.status value will changed.

This is my HTML

```
<button ng-click="status(x);" ng-switch="x.status">
    <span ng-switch-when="orderer">SHOW</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="orderer_hidden">HIDE</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="creator">SHOW</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="creator_hidden">HIDE</span>
</button>
```

The ng-switch will trigger only when I refresh the page.

UPDATED

This is the script

```
$scope.status = function(data){
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: Ajax_call.ajaxurl,
            params: {
                id: data.id,
                status: data.status,
                action: "status_changed"
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: And what, it doesn't work? You probably have `orderer` out of your model/controller scope, then.

Comment: Yes its not working I tried the ng-switch but it doesnt change the text when I click it

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization you need to share the javascript also for any help.

Comment: @NarenMurali the script are just for sending ajax.

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization ok got it, the button does not change the text, so what does change the text? you have not shared the controller code, or the HTML code where the x.status is changed. If possible share a JSFiddle with the issue.

Comment: @NarenMurali Thats my question to make it behave like a ng-changed so that it will changed the text. I tried this one `<button ng-click="status(x);" ng-switch="x.status" ng-changed='changed()'>` and in the controller `$scope.status = function(data){$scope.changed = function(data){//send ajax here }}`

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization I think that you need to rerun the initial ajax that populates `x` (I am talking about the ajax which runs when the page is refreshed), the problem is that there is not enough code to give you a good explanation.

Comment: @NarenMurali so im going to have a then in in $http? and manually put it in ng-switch?

Comment: @NarenMurali for example `$http({//ajax request}).then(function(result){$scope.x.status = result.status});` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152891/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-pure-rhymer-organization).